# How to suppress the "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" message?

Tags: python

Can I suppress the "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" message in the following code?

```
>>> from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
>>> pearsonr([1,1,1], [1,2,3])
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:2471: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  r = r_num / r_den
(nan, 1.0)
```

I have tried exception catch and handling, but it doesn't  work

```
try:
    pearsonr([1,1,1], [1,2,3])
except:
    pass
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch warning using `warnings.filterwarnings`

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error')
try:
    pearsonr([1,1,1], [1,2,3])
except:
    pass
```